# HTML5 Audio Event Tracking in Google Analytics?

Tags: html, audio, google-analytics, html5-audio

I don't have a live sample as I'm not sure where to go from the following but any help would be greatly appreciated.

The Want:
I would like to have several hundred audio samples throughout my site but need to know how many times each of them are played from within Google Analytics.

I have found the following code at https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/events but having so many samples I need to be able to add something or write a function or whatever to avoid having to do this for each sample.

```
ga('send', 'event', [eventCategory], [eventAction], [eventLabel], [eventValue], [fieldsObject]);
```

Thank you for your suggestions in advance :)

Comment: You should use GTM so that you can track all your audio interactions with just one set of tags (no need to code each and every file).

Comment: While it does not do exactly what I need there is a tutorial that I found at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lDMlw8CLgvA that points me in the right direction.  This seems to be more complicated than I originally thought it would be.  I use the Divi Wordpress theme and it uses <button> with no id or class for playing if that helps anyone get me a little further :)

Comment: Hi, Brandon,  you will need to show some of the code for your Audio elements. I was thinking that you could simply attach a specific class to those audio elements and use that as a trigger for the interaction.

Comment: you are both correct in that I needed to create the click event in GTM as well as adding a unique class to each audio players.  I am now looking into how to accomplish the addition of classes to the default Wordpress audio play buttons.  The new question to avoid confusion since its a completely different issue is at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44312608/add-custom-id-to-wordpress-audio-player-play-button

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to use Google Tag Manager and create a custom event that tracks all clicks on the audio player button and adds to Analytics labelled as either the buttons class or ID.

A great tutorial for GTM Event Tracking can be found at:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lDMlw8CLgvA