# Add custom ID to Wordpress Audio Player Play Button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I have a page with several players on it and a click event setup in Google Tag Manager.  That said the play button that is clicked has no class or id for the tracking to label it with.  I need to give each players play button a unique class or ID that when clicked has something to pass to GTM.

Basically when the player shows on my site it comes in as:

```
<button type="button" aria-controls="mep_0" title="Play" aria-label="Play"></button>
```

And I would like it to be:

```
<button type="button" aria-controls="mep_0" title="Play" aria-label="Play" id="audio title or some unique identifier"></button>
```

Thank you all in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Surely there is something unique about the buttons to play different audio, but you may be able to do something like this:

(I don't know if this has to exist before tag manager loads up)

```js
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('button[aria-label="Play"]');
for(let i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++){
 buttons[i].setAttribute('id', 'playBttn'+i);
}
console.log(buttons);
```

```html
<button type="button" aria-controls="mep_0" title="Play" aria-label="Play"></button>
<button type="button" aria-controls="mep_0" title="Play" aria-label="Play"></button>
<button type="button" aria-controls="mep_0" title="Play" aria-label="Play"></button>
<button type="button" aria-controls="mep_0" title="Play" aria-label="Play"></button>
<button type="button" aria-controls="mep_0" title="Play" aria-label="Play"></button>
```

Comment: There is nothing unique to the gtm.click event because the button is being clicked not the audio element itself that holds the src path to the mp3 and the button does not have a class or id as shown above.  This said I need the class or id to be used as the label for GTM so while Unique it needs to be identifiable (i.e. song name or mp3 name, etc.) so that when looking at the reports I can see more than just a number of clicks.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What plugin are you using for that audio player ?

In order to do that, you have to change the shortcode of this plugin so it will allow to put another param in the shortcode, for example :

[myplayer file="mymusic.mp3" id="1"]

Then in the php file, you can put the new param "id" in the generated html.

Comment: I'm just using the default Wordpress audio shortcode that is found at https://codex.wordpress.org/Audio_Shortcode.  I am working out how to add the src filename as an id without physically adding it to each and every sample manually

Answer (score 0):

I was researching this very issue and came up with a solution. Its a bit hacky but it does work for my needs.

it requires a hack to wpincludes/mediaelements/mediaelement-and-player.min.js (I plan an creating a plugin to to do this at some point...)

Find the section for the play button  add a new id and class to the button. The id is grabbed by google tag manager and the class is updated with the post title.

```
('<div class="mejs-button mejs-playpause-button mejs-play" ><button id="perplay" class="playername" type="button" aria-controls="'+g.id+'" title="'+h.playText+'" aria-label="'+h.playText+'"></button></div>').
```

In each wordpress theme content page (content.php, content-single.php, content-front.php, etc)

Find the audio/video section

```
<div class="entry-content video">

<!-- Underneath it add the following code -->

<!-- hack to add podcast name (post title) to the player button class -->
    <?php $x = get_the_title(); // gets post title ?>   
    <script>
        <!-- js to find element with class name of playername and append the class name with the post title -->
        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
         document.getElementsByClassName('playername')[0].className = " <?php  echo $x; ?>";
})
</script>
```

in my case I was then able to get the element.css value in Google tag manager and use that to track what audio file was played and on which page it was played on.

If you need to track more than one audio file per post you could probably get the media id and use that instead of the post title - tho in GA you would need a lookup table if you have a lot of IDs.

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is old, but if someone else ever searches for this like I did, don't overthink it or hack core files. You only need to configure a Click Element matching the following CSS selector (or right click play button to inspect, right click the button tag, and then copy selector) :

```
#mep_0 > div > div.mejs-controls > div.mejs-button.mejs-playpause-button.mejs-play > button
```

That is your selector and no need to have an id attribute specifically set on the button.

[Screenshot of Trigger Configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k7bs3.png)

Note that each additional player on the same page will increase the "mep ID" like #mep_1, #mep_2, etc. You set up a Google Analytics: Universal Analytics tag with the event, category, action, and label you want to show in analytics when triggered and create a tag and trigger for each button to track the play button clicks individually. You could name the label the filename of the audio file or whatever you want it to show up as in GA. Use the GTM Copy/Paste extension to duplicate easily.

[Screenshot of Tag Configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pmKAP.png)

I use this method to track plays on podcasts where there may be multiple embedded players on the same page. Each shows up with it's own label in GA. Additionally, I have the trigger check the page path or URL so that the trigger only fires and tracks play clicks for play buttons on specific pages. GTM can be intimidating at first, but it's pretty easy once you start playing around and testing with Tag Assistant.